# UICollectionViewCell reuse causing incorrect UISwitch state

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am having trouble finding a solution for this issue.
I am using `UISwitch` inside `UICollectionViewCell` and I am passing a boolean variable to set switch on or off.

The condition is only one switch has to be ON at a time from all cells.
But When I turn one switch on another random switch's tint color changes that means its state changed.

By default switch status is ON in storyboard and even if I set it OFF nothing changes.

I couldn't figure out why is this happening.

[image]

Here is my code for `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AddEditItemPopupView.cellId, for: indexPath) as! DiscountCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self

        let currentDiscount = allDiscounts[indexPath.item]
        let shouldApplyDiscount = updatedDiscountId == currentDiscount.id
        cell.updateCellWith(data: currentDiscount, applyDiscount: shouldApplyDiscount)
        return cell
    }
```

And code for cell class

```
func updateCellWith(data: DiscountModel, applyDiscount: Bool) {
        let name = data.title.replacingOccurrences(of: "Discount ", with: "")
        self.titleLabel.text = String(format: "%@ (%.2f%%)", name, data.value)
        self.switchApply.isOn = applyDiscount
        self.switchApply.tag = data.id
    }
```

Data source contains objects of `DiscountModel` which look like this:

```
{
    id: Int!
    title: String!
    value: Double!
}
```

Switch value changed method inside cell class:

```
@IBAction func switchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            self.delegate?.switchValueDidChangeAt(index: sender.tag)
        }
        else{
            self.delegate?.switchValueDidChangeAt(index: 0)
        }
    }
```

Delegate method inside view controller class:

```
func switchValueDidChangeAt(index: Int) {
        self.updatedDiscountId = index
        self.discountCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: If this is happening without scrolling, it might not be cell reuse. Is it a static or dynamic collection view?

Comment: Also, what is switchApply?

Comment: @Chris switchApply is an outlet of UISwitch from collectionViewCell. Its a dynamic collection view and currently contains only 4 cells which fits within the width of collectionView and yes this is happening without scrolling. So what could cause this issue?

Comment: I feel like these two lines might be the problem (but not sure): `let currentDiscount = ...` and `let shouldApplyDiscount = ...`

Comment: Nope, I debugged and verified that shouldApplyDiscount has correct value for each index every time when switch status is changed.

Comment: You could have an integer variable in the collection view delegate view controller that is changed and changed in the `cellForRow` method depending on the switch. This would mean only one could be activated.

Comment: Cool, thanks for info

Comment: @Chris Sorry couldn't understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: @Sulthan If I dont use tags how would I be able to identify which switch's value changed?

Comment: Show us the delegate that handles clicks. Show how you are using tags. I am also worried about the color change. It seems the tint color is changing for some reason too. Are you setting that in code somewhere?

Comment: @Sulthan Please have a look at updated question and I am not setting tint color in code, all those are defaults in storyboard.

Comment: Could you try to change `.isOn = applyDiscount` to `self.switchApply.setOn(applyDiscount, animated: false)`?

Comment: @Sulthan Tried already, nothing changes.

Comment: What you are doing is somewhat problematic. When you click the switch, it starts an animation but you immediately reload the cell, resetting `isOn`, therefore cancelling the animation. I would try either `if switchApply.isOn != applyDiscount { switchApply.isOn = applyDiscount }` or `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.switchApply.isOn = applyDiscount }`. A possible solution is also to disable interaction on the switch and handle clicks (selection) on the whole cell instead.

Comment: @Sulthan It works if I handle clicks on cell.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few improvements I would suggest to your code;

- Reloading the entire collection view is a bit of a shotgun
- Since it is possible for there to be no discount applied, you should probably use an optional for your selected discount, rather than "0"
- Using `Tag` is often problematic

I would use something like:

```
var currentDiscount: DiscountModel? = nil

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AddEditItemPopupView.cellId, for: indexPath) as! DiscountCollectionViewCell
    cell.delegate = self

    let item = allDiscounts[indexPath.item]
    self.configure(cell, forItem: item)

    return cell
}

func configure(_ cell: DiscountCollectionViewCell, forItem item: DiscountModel) {
    cell.switchApply.isOn = false
    let name = item.title.replacingOccurrences(of: "Discount ", with: "")
    self.titleLabel.text = String(format: "%@ (%.2f%%)", name, item.value)

    guard let selectedDiscount = self.currentDiscount else {
        return
    }

    cell.switchApply.isOn = selectedDiscount.id == item.id
}

func switchValueDidChangeIn(cell: DiscountCollectionViewCell, to value: Bool) {
    if value {
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
           self.currentDiscount = self.allDiscounts[indexPath.item]
        }
    } else {
        self.currentDiscount = nil
    }
    for indexPath in collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            self.configure(cell, forItem: self.allDiscounts[indexPath.item])
        }
    }
}
```

In your cell:

```
@IBAction func switchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    self.delegate?.switchValueDidChangeIn(cell:self, to: sender.isOn)
}
```